# How to add numbers from a sequence that contains numbers and letters in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, substring

lets say the user submits this sequence: dadeer50dfder625dsf3 , the program should print the result of the sum of the numbers : 50+625+3. How can i do this ?

This is what i have done so far, but its not working. Can someone help me please :( :

```
String secuencia = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa tu secuencia");
           int par = secuencia.length();
                     int sumatoria = 0;
         int sumatoria1 = 0;
                          for (int i = 0; i < par; i++) {
            String p = secuencia.substring(i, i +1); 
                        if(p.equals("1") || p.equals("2") || p.equals("3") || p.equals("4") || p.equals("5") || p.equals("6") || p.equals("7") || p.equals("8") || p.equals("9") || p.equals("0")){
                                for (int j = i + 1; j < par; j++) {
                                String n = secuencia.substring(j, j + 1);
                                 if(n.equals("1") || n.equals("2") || n.equals("3") || n.equals("4") || n.equals("5") || n.equals("6") || n.equals("7") || n.equals("8") || n.equals("9") || n.equals("0")){

                                     int v = Integer.parseInt(p);
                                     int y = Integer.parseInt(n);
                          sumatoria += v;       
                                     sumatoria1 += y ;

                        }      }}           

                        System.out.print(sumatoria);
                        System.out.println(sumatoria1);
```

Comment: Using Regular Expressions will get the job done quickly. Are you allowed to use them?

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean with regular expressions (ive only been coding for about a month), im supposed to use substring, for loops and lenght.

Comment: Ok then I have an answer for you, I'll post it in a minute

Comment: Roberto, please describe exactly *how* it's "not working". Are you getting an exception? The wrong answer (what is the expected and actual output)? Something else?

Comment: for example, if i write 44, i get 44 as an answers, if i write 444 i got 88, 1212, 1212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple code without using RegEx's like you told us in the commentaries :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "55blhalhalh3265hezubf565";
    boolean isLetter = false;
    String temp = "";
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++){
        switch(str.charAt(i)){
        case '0': 
        case '1': 
        case '2': 
        case '3': 
        case '4': 
        case '5': 
        case '6': 
        case '7': 
        case '8': 
        case '9':
            isLetter = false;
            temp += str.charAt(i);
            break;
        default :
            if (!isLetter)sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);
            isLetter = true;
            temp = "";
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isLetter) sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);

    System.out.println("The final sum is " + sum);
}
```

I made the switch long on purpose to be very clear.

A little explanation :

The `for` iterates over all the chars of your `String` object of course.
Then, the `switch` checks if it is a number or not :

- if it is the case, the boolean isLetter takes the false value and we concatenate the char to the previous number if there was
- if it is a letter, we add the already found number to the total sum.

Comment: This actually helped the problem, thank you very much and also thanks to everybody else who took their time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), which takes a regular expression. I think you want non-digits, so you could use `\\D+`. Something like,

```
String str = "dadeer50dfder625dsf3";
String[] arr = str.split("\\D+");
int total = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String val : arr) {
    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    sb.append(val).append(" + ");
    total += Integer.parseInt(val);
}
sb.replace(sb.length() - 2, sb.length(), "= ");
System.out.print(sb);
System.out.println(total);
```

And the output is

```
50 + 625 + 3 = 678
```

Answer (score 0):

Roberto,

It looks like you are on the right path, however the problem with your code is that it assumes the number is only a single character long. I think it adds 5+0+6+2+5+3 instead of the desired add.

I would suggest using the function String.split() to seperate out the pieces which contain numbers and the pieces that do not. I believe you can pass something like [A-Za-z] and that will return strings that only contain numbers in them(Assuming only letters and not other characters are used).
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions.
The first shows how easy it is when using regular expression.
The second uses the constraints given in a comment. Since it said "substring", I'll assume that using `Integer.parseInt()` is ok.

```
// Using regular expression
String text = "dadeer50dfder625dsf3";
int sum = 0;
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(text); m.find(); )
    sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
System.out.println(sum);

// Using only substring, for loops and length
String text = "dadeer50dfder625dsf3";
int sum = 0, numStart = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    char c = text.charAt(i);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        if (numStart == -1)
            numStart = i;
    } else {
        if (numStart != -1)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(text.substring(numStart, i));
        numStart = -1;
    }
}
if (numStart != -1)
    sum += Integer.parseInt(text.substring(numStart));
System.out.println(sum);
```

*Output from both*

```
678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "dadeer50dfder625dsf3";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\D+"));
    int sum = 0;
    for (String each : list) {
        try {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(each);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```